# Can I add Middleware dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have 2 types of authorizations on my site. I want to create a generic middleware, which will address request to the corresponding middlewares.
For example:

```
if ($request->headers->has('token')) {
        // Execute token middleware
}

if ($request->headers->has('authorization')) {
        // Execute some logics
        // Call `auth:sanctum` middleware
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can assign middlewares to routes itself.

Comment: You can write your middleware so that it does nothing when the token is not present. You can apply the Decorator Pattern to do so without touching existing middlewares.

Comment: @nice_dev I tried adding middleware to the route using `$request->route()->middleware('auth:sanctum')`, but it didn't work.


@UlrichEckhardt The problem is that I don't know which class is responsible for `auth:sanctum` middleware, if I knew, I could directly call it in my middleware

Comment: @randomacc This looks like adding a middleware to the route at runtime. You need to assign it right where it is declared. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes

Comment: @randomacc check this https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-call-middleware-from-controller-in-laravelexample.html

Comment: Just to clarify, will the routes you attach this middleware to work with both token or sanctum?

Answer (score 3):

You can supply multiple guards to Laravel's `auth` middleware. The middleware will cycle through the provided guards in order and use the first one that it can authenticate with:

```
Route::middleware('auth:token,sanctum')->group(function () {
    // your other routes
});
```

You can do this with any or all the guards you have set up in Laravel (config/auth.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply middleware in your controllers and scope them to specific methods in the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Middleware only applied to these methods
    $this->middleware('your-middleware', [
        'only' => [
            'update',
            'create'
        ]
    ]);
}
```